# I am working with Dask, what are the advantages of using Datashader for the dataviz instead of the classic Seaborn in Python?

Tags: python, dask

It is the first time I am working on a Machine Learning model with Dask, but before splitting the data I have to produce some visualisations of basic descriptive statistics. I have read that Datashader is "smoother" than Seaborn when working with Dask. What I don't understand is what makes that library optimal when parallelising with Dask. Is there any substantive advantage in terms of performance? By the way, I'm using the describe() method to calculate the descriptive statistics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Datashader directly supports Dask distributed DataFrames, which means that if you have data distributed across many worker nodes, Datashader can render each bit of the data on that local worker, and then assemble the resulting partial renderings into a final single image for display on your screen. You can also use Seaborn to plot your data from Dask, but you'll first need to pull out a feasible subset (a selection or aggregation) that will fit onto a single machine with Pandas, and then use Seaborn with that reduced Pandas version of your data.

To get started with Datashader+Dask, I'd recommend using hvPlot, which integrates those two packages and makes them work easily together. See examples at https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Plotting.html , after doing "import hvplot.dask", and to use Datashader add `rasterize=True` or `datashade=True` to your .hvplot() call. Datashader is optional with hvPlot, but you'll definitely want to use it if your data is large enough to require a distributed Dask setup!